# Getting a count while accounting for an attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one for account information and one for customer information. An account can have multiple customers associated with it. What I want to do is grab all active customers in a given month. However, I also want to account for customers who are active and purchased in earlier months.

```
Account
ID  IND_ID  LAST_PURCHASE  
1   101       2013-01-15
2   102       2013-03-20
2   103       2013-02-05
3   104       2013-07-25
4   105       2012-01-11

Customer
ID   STATUS  
101   A
102   A
103   A
104   E
105   A
```

Select just the active customers is not the issue as I can just filter on that column. However, how can I select the count of active 'customers' while accounting for people who purchased in the past two month.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a couple things here.  Please consider showing the expected output based on your test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by looking at the maximum purchase date and filtering on that:

```
select c.id
from customer c join
     account a
     on c.id = a.ind_id
where c.status = 'A'
group by c.id
having max(last_purchase) >= date_add(month, -2, getdate());
```